# Using multinomial logit to rank observations

Tags: regression, multinomial-distribution, logit, ranking

I'm trying to devise a model to rank a number of links according to their popularity. The links refer to upcoming events and job offers, and ideally I'd like to have a reasonably simple model that, given the values of some covariates such as the number of clicks on the link and the number of days remaining till the event, would provide me with a value I could use to rank the observations according to their popularity. What is actually needed is a list of the top-ten events.

My initial, naive, approach was to ask the committent to rank a small subset of the observations into three ordinal categories, namely "High", "Average" and "Low" popularity. I then reasoned that having something like a training dataset I could try fitting a multinomial logistic regression, and then I could sort the observations according to the predicted probability of falling into the "High" popularity category; i.e., given a subset of covariates $X$ the closer the predicted probability $P(``High"|X)$ gets to 1 the closer to the top that observation gets.

What do you think about this approach? This seems a problem suited for machine learning methods, about which sadly I know next to nothing. Is there a more exact term for what I'm trying to do? I'd be grateful for any pointer to the relevant literature, altough keep in mind the "solution" has to be quite simple, a single equation would be ideal.

Thank you for your time!